# How it will taste if one puts two substances on tongue simultaneously?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, food-chemistry, taste

If we put two substances having different taste on tongue simultaneously how it will taste? Does specific part of tongue is sensitive to specific taste?

Comment: The popular "tongue map," which depicts the tongue having distinct regions where you can only taste certain tastes, is completely inaccurate and was debunked quite a while ago. There are regions of the tongue that are *slightly* more sensitive to tastes, however. A google search of "taste map" or "tongue map" will yield links on the origins of the myth.

Comment: This would perhaps be more suited for the Cooking site :-)  Though most taste is actually smell.